# OAuth2 Resource Credentials Flow Exception Caught

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

Using doorkeeper with a client side gem for OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow

My request body is:

```
{
"grant_type": "password",
"username": "test@test.com",
"password": "sekret"
}
```

and endpoint for the POST is: `localhost:8080/api/v1/oauth/token`

I can get the grant_type: client_credentials to respond with a token...but the password param (which I need) responds with:

```
        <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
```

Any ideas as to why? Using doorkeeper 4.0 with a rails angular app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [RFC6749 section 2.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1), your data should not be passed through a JSON object, but as body request (`grant_type=password&username=test%40test.com&password=sekret`) with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header.